# VBA Datatype Mismatch Error 13

Tags: string, vba, date, ms-access

I have looked this piece of code over several times and am not sure why the string is not converting to data structure date. Please help with why it might be happening. I tried to concatenate "#" & dataFROM & "#" in the final search where clause which works in another form. It may be the complex conditions from the If statement that is making this more work.

```
Private Sub txtTHRU_AfterUpdate()
Dim dataFROM As Date
Dim dataTHRU As Date
Dim myLabelsExpiration As String
dataFROM = txtFROM.Value
dataTHRU = txtTHRU.Value
If dataFROM Is Not Null And dataTHRU Is Not Null Then
myLabelsExpiration = "Select * from [Members] where ([Expire] Between #" & dataFROM & "# AND #" & dataTHRU & "#)"
Me.MembersWithFriendsSubform.Form.RecordSource = membershipCutoff
Me.MembersWithFriendsSubform.Form.Requery
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nulls are handled differently between VBA and SQL.

The below logic expression does not work in VBA:

```
If dataFROM Is Not Null And dataTHRU Is Not Null Then
```

Change to use the `IsNull()` boolean function:

```
If IsNull(dataFROM) And IsNull(dataTHRU) Then
```

Comment: Add also a true or false condition if you need. such as IsNull(dataFROM) = False in the case that data was entered. But now my Between where clause is giving me a name? error on MS Access.

Comment: Got that figured out. The variable was from another code block.

Answer (score 0):

Use CDate. It's fairly simple to use. If your string is "August 7, 2015", you would do this:

```
CDate("August 7, 2015")
```

In your specific case, it would be like this:

```
dataFROM = CDate(txtFROM.Value)
dataTHRU = CDate(txtTHRU.Value)
```

EDIT: You should also look up `DateValue` and `TimeValue`. Those can be used in very similar ways to get just the date or just the time. I use them when I'm trying to specifically seperate the date and time. Otherwise, I mostly use CDate.

Comment: I tried this. The part where the null is giving the issue it highlights it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set variables of Date to Null.

Also, you don't need the date values but their string expressions. Thus:

```
Private Sub txtTHRU_AfterUpdate()

    Dim dataFROM As String
    Dim dataTHRU As String
    Dim myLabelsExpiration As String

    If Not IsNull(Me!txtFROM.Value +  Me!txtTHRU.Value) Then
        dataFROM = Format(Me!txtFROM.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
        dataTHRU = Format(Me!txtTHRU.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
        myLabelsExpiration = "Select * From [Members] Where [Expire] Between #" & dataFROM & "# And #" & dataTHRU & "#"

        If Me!MembersWithFriendsSubform.Form.RecordSource = membershipCutoff Then
            Me!MembersWithFriendsSubform.Form.Requery
        Else
            Me!MembersWithFriendsSubform.Form.RecordSource = membershipCutoff
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of 
If dataFROM **Is Not Null** And dataTHRU Is Not Null Then 
try using
If **Not IsNull**(dataFROM) And Not IsNull(dataTHRU) Then